# Creating dynamic fields in CRM

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create a `Entity` which can hold fields which will be dynamic

Let's say I have a `Entity` named **Party** and another entity named **People**, each party can hold N number of people names

How should I create such record?

Is there any other way other than creating `fields` like **People1**, **People2** as `lookup` to the people entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look what N:N relationship is. You will not have exactly fields but you will have possibility to put subgrid of People type to Party entity to know what People belong to this Party and vice versa.

Comment: Agree to Andrii. Just to add on that. You can extend the solution to associate multiple entities associated with party entity as per the business requirement.